# Getting "Mute State" in ARI

Tags: node.js, express, asterisk, voip, freepbx

Been fiddling around with ARI, node.js all that good stuff, but in my front end web application am having an issue with a visual bug every me I refresh the page all buttons go back to mute, so in order to set this right I had an Idea.

Simply pull out the mute state (if possible) to set the value in the front end, problem being is I don't know if its possible to get a mute state.

Anyone any guidance on this, been trying in the CLI and searching for commands which would help me and getting detail about the channel never states if a channel is muted or not.

Is it even possible to do this without using developed applications like fop/fop2 and just use the CLI/ARI to do this? Am still relatively new to ARI and asterisk.

EDIT: Tried various CLI Commands and it only gives state "Up" "down" when showing channels or channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check already developed projects like fop/fop2.

Use core "show channels"&'sip show peers"/"iax2 show peers" to get current state.

Comment: Company already using fop2 and ave tried that but it doesnt tell me if a channel is muted or not.

Comment: So you need extend fop2 to catch mute event.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, kind of takes away the point of developing an application in ARI. Not intending on using already developed projects when am developing my own to meet a different set of requirements.

Comment: Sorry, there are no real question in your answer. Only answer can be - you have read more about asterisk internals. Yes, it is posible. No, you still have learn. SO not give answer if you not understand question, check FAQ.

Comment: I understand my own question...Can you get a mute state from asterisk, yes technically you answered my question in suggesting fop/fop2 as a method to do so.....but that's not what I was looking for and that requires a rewording of my initial question which am sorry for, but is it possible to do it without fop and just use asterisk CLI or ARI in some way to do this? That is the real question. Am fully aware of what am asking.

Comment: No,you can't get mute state. You can only spot events and save it. So you have collect ALL events, filter mute events, save that for your use.